# Should I use 向前 or 向后？

Tags: translation

(Sorry, @hinen. I use your answer as my question.)

当我比较 [hinen 的答案](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/posts/22572/revisions)时，我有一个疑问。

原来的内容是：

> 這樣我們就知道要向前找。
>   So, we know that we should look up forward.

他/她修改，只把​​ forward 改成 backward，没改中文。

他/她先在第170图，后来到第156图，是向书本页数较少的方向找。
英文用 backward，但中文用"向前"还是"向后"？

backward 在字典中的翻译是"向后方"。
但中文的"向后方"可以是向书本的后面，也就是向页数较多的方向。

所以，forward 和 backward 中文要如何说才清楚，用查字典做例子？

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(It's my honor that somebody can use my answer.
It's also my bad that I didn't use good words.)

The following expressions may help.

look up forward
往尾查
往後頁查
查後面的頁數
向字典後面查
向多的頁數查
繼續向下查

look up backward
往頭查
往前頁查
查前面的頁數
向字典前面查
向少的頁數查
回頭往前查